# Testing JQuery UI autocomplete with Capybara + Env.js does not work (with Selenium it works)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, integration-testing, envjs

I do an RSpec integration test of the JQuery UI autocomplete functionality by using Capybara. When using Selenium (+ Firefox) as the web driver for Capybara everything works as it should, but when switching to Env.js as driver my tests fail. Are those known shortcomings of Env.js, or do I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby/Johnson port of env.js has some holes in event support that tend to crop up when using jquery, particularly the latest release, which relies more heavily on live/bubbled events, and jquery.ui.

Moreover, autocomplete is particularly problematic since as a virtual browser, env.js has no keyboard or mouse from which to generate change and focus events.

env.js is generally developed by people scratching their own itches, so you're welcome/encouraged to contribute.